# use of indefinite article (help with sentence example)

Tags: sentence-construction, articles, indefinite-article

> The job required **an** impressive intelligence and strength.
>
> The job required impressive intelligence and strength.

Are they both correct? What's their difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both are correct.

The first implies **an impressive combination of intelligence and strength**.

It suggests that these two qualities come together to help the person concerned measure up to the job requirements.

The second describes them as separate but equally essential qualities.

The difference is slight. It's really just a question of nuance.